# About the signature SignC in XADES4J

Tags: java, xades4j

I would like to have some informations about SignerCTest because actually I have some problems :

in my Main class :

```
public class XadesTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            SignerCTest signerCTest = new SignerCTest();
            System.out.println("signerCTest :  " + signerCTest.toString());
            signerCTest.testSignC();    
    }
```

In my SignerCTest.class :

```
      public class SignerCTest extends SignerTestBase
{
    //@Test
    public void testSignC() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("signC");

        Document doc = getTestDocument();
        Element elemToSign = doc.getDocumentElement();

        ValidationDataProvider vdp = new ValidationDataFromCertValidationProvider(VerifierTestBase.validationProviderNist);
        SignerC signer = (SignerC)new XadesCSigningProfile(keyingProviderNist, vdp).newSigner();
        new Enveloped(signer).sign(elemToSign);

        outputDocument(doc, "document.signed.c.xml");


    }
}
```

and I have these errors :

```
signerCTest :  xadestest.SignerCTest@345b43
signC
Exception in thread "main" xades4j.providers.ValidationDataException: Cannot validate certificate: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at xades4j.providers.impl.ValidationDataFromCertValidationProvider.getValidationData(ValidationDataFromCertValidationProvider.java:54)
    at xades4j.production.SignerC.getFormatSpecificSignatureProperties(SignerC.java:70)
    at xades4j.production.SignerBES.sign(SignerBES.java:200)
    at xades4j.production.Enveloped.sign(Enveloped.java:69)
    at xadestest.SignerCTest.testSignC(SignerCTest.java:45)
    at xadestest.XadesTest.main(XadesTest.java:84)
Caused by: xades4j.providers.CannotBuildCertificationPathException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at xades4j.providers.impl.PKIXCertificateValidationProvider.validate(PKIXCertificateValidationProvider.java:142)
    at xades4j.providers.impl.ValidationDataFromCertValidationProvider.getValidationData(ValidationDataFromCertValidationProvider.java:51)
    ... 5 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 17 seconds)
```

But the cetificate are well here :

```
D:\NetBeansProjects_MYSIGN\XadesTest\src\test\cert\my\LG.pfx

D:\NetBeansProjects_MYSIGN\XadesTest\src\test\cert\csrc.nist\test4.p12
```

So... I don't understand. Can anybody help me ?

Thanks,
William.

Answer (score 2):

The test you're using relies on certificates from NIST only.

The `CertificateValidationProvider` that the test is using (`VerifierTestBase.validationProviderNist`) has certificate revocation check enabled. Also, note that it is created with a `CertStore` that reflects the contents of the *csrc.nist* folder. This means that the *csrc.nist* folder must contain the CRLs and other intermediate certificates, so that the provider can build the certificate chain and check the revocation status.